# preg_match not allowing searches with spaces

Tags: php, json, preg-match

Have looked around for solution to the issue. My search is getting JSON data from the musixmatch api however the search only works with single words, e.g searching 'mamma' or 'mia' returns results but searching 'mamma mia' is not returning results. The API is using UTF-8 and my document is set to the same. I have tried to solve this with preg_match. See my php below for the index.php page:

**What I expected**
After entering search query with spaces to return results. e.g 'Mamma Mia'

**Actual outcome**
No search results. only works when users search for single phrase 'Mamma' or 'Mia'

Here is a working page: http://songfind.co.uk/lyrics-find

```html
<form id"lyricsform" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="GET">
   <input type="text" id="lyricinputtype" name="q"/>
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
   <select name="songtype" id="lyricstype">
      <option name="song" value="song">Song Title</option>
      <option name="artist" value="artist">Artist</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
<?php
   $query = $_GET['term'];
   $apikey = 'MYAPIKEY';
   $apicall = 'http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_track='.$query.'&apikey='.$apikey;
   $url = file_get_contents($apicall);
   $json = json_decode($url);
   
   $nameErr = "";
   $query = "";
   
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
   if (empty($_GET["q"])) {
   $nameErr = "Song Title or Artist is Required";
   } else {
   $query = test_input($_GET["q"]);
   
   // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
   
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$query)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
   }
   }
   
   echo 'You are searching for the Song: ' .$query;
                   
   foreach($json->message->body->track_list as $track_list) {
   echo '<div style="float: left; width: 100%; display: block;">';
   echo '<p style="float:left; margin-right:10px;"><img src="'.$track_list->track->album_coverart_100x100.'"></p>';
   echo '<h2> Track Title: '.$track_list->track->track_name.'</h2>';
   echo '<p> Artist Name: '.$track_list->track->artist_name.'</p>';
   $track_id = $track_list->track->track_id;
   
   //URL gets passed to lyrics.php to display the data on separate page
   
   echo '<a href="lyrics.php/track.lyrics.get?track_id='.$track_list->track->track_id.'">View Lyrics</a>';
   echo '</div>';
   }
   
   function test_input($data) {
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
   }
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: have you tried using url_decode()? And whats the Output of $_GET['q']?

Comment: If you create a [MCVE example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you'll have a better chance to get a good answer. Right now it takes a lot of effort to examine your code and understand it and it is not clear what the desired behavior of the code is.

Comment: @Nima I have updated the code and question to hopefully make it easier to understand

Comment: @Bernhard how would I go about using your suggestion in my code, I am fairly new to php

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$query = $_GET['term'];
$queryEncoded = urlencode($query); <-- I encoded search term.
$apikey = 'MYAPIKEY';
$apicall = 'http://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.search?q_track='.$queryEncoded.'&apikey='.$apikey;
```